# Forward emails in deferred queue to particular email address

Tags: email, postfix

I have about 15 emails in `deferred queue` destined to `johndoe@example.com` .Below is mailq sample

```
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
0531B51E5501*    1354 Mon May  8 19:15:18  johndoe@example.com
                                         mary@abc.com

EB01051E83E4*    1333 Tue May  9 22:50:29  johndoe@example.com
                                         batman@jelly.org
...
...
...
```

i tried to edit `/etc/postfix/virtual` but it forwards only for new emails and doesnt work in existing emails in deferred queue

Answer (score 3):

`postsuper -r` is what you're looking for. From the man page:

> -r queue_id
>                 Requeue the message with the named queue ID from the named  mail
>                 queue(s) (default: hold, incoming, active and deferred).

Additionally, you may want to specify `ALL` if your intention is to process all of the deferred messages.

> Specify  "-r  ALL" to requeue all messages. As a safety measure,
>                 the word ALL must be specified in upper case.

[postsuper(1)](http://www.postfix.org/postsuper.1.html)